# Trying to run Python 3.10 from Terminal after Homebrew install

Tags: homebrew, macos-monterey, apple-silicon, python-3.10

I used the Homebrew command `brew install python@3.10` to install Python3.10 on my Mac.
However, when I'm in Terminal and type `python` and then press Tab, it is only giving me the option for the Python 3 that's located in my /usr/bin/
How do I enter the 3.10 interpreter that's located in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/

Answer (score 2):

Running `brew info python@3.10` will give you the solution to your problem:

```
If you need to have python@3.10 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```